# Can $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}$ be an integer?

Tags: number-theory, integers

The number $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ cannot be an integer if $a,b$ are integers such that $\sqrt{b}$ is not an integer. (In fact, this is true for any number of square roots, and I believe even for cube roots, etc.) Therefore $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ cannot be an integer either, for any positive integer $n$.

What about if we sum it with the conjugate? That is, do there exist positive integers $n\geq 2,a,b$ such that $\sqrt{b}$ is not an integer but $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}$ is an integer?

*Update*: As Jyrki Lahtonen points out in the comment, there do exist such integers. What about if we also require that $\sqrt{a}$ is not an integer either?

Comment: If you had $a+\sqrt{b}$ instead, I would say it's possible. But in your case, the second part is not really a conjugate - because $\sqrt{a}$ is not an integer

Comment: I was thinking of conjugate in the sense that $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})$ is an integer. But the question Is still interesting in your case, I believe.

Comment: But you are not multiplying the two expressions, you are adding them. How do you think $\sqrt{a}$ is supposed to 'disappear' in this case? I don't think it's possible. I might be mistaken, of course, I hope someone will correct me if it's the case

Comment: Fine, I get your point. I'll edit to remove the assumption that $\sqrt{a}$ is not an integer.

Comment: If you drop the assumption that $\sqrt{a}$ is not an integer, then you get plenty of examples. For example
$$(2+\sqrt3)^3=26+15\sqrt3=\sqrt{676}+\sqrt{675}$$ and similarly
$(2-\sqrt3)^3=\sqrt{676}-\sqrt{675}$, so
$$\root3\of{\sqrt{676}+\sqrt{675}}+\root3\of{\sqrt{676}-\sqrt{675}}=4.$$
You can similarly reverse engineer the sum of cube roots of the cubes of any conjugate pair $u\pm\sqrt v$.

Comment: This is not possible for $n = 2$; it boils down to requiring $\sqrt a + \sqrt{a - b} \in \Bbb N$, which is only possible if both of these are in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: If you look at cube roots (or any odd roots), clearly $\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{-a} = 0$ which is an integer. If you're willing to work with complex numbers a similar thing holds for square roots as well.

Comment: $a,b$ must be positive integers, so neither of them can be set to $0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Pell's equations solve the problem.

Let

$$A.N'^{2}+1=M'^{2}$$

the generic Pell equation, the solution of which is:

$N’=\frac{(M+N\sqrt{A})^{n}}{2\sqrt{A}}-\frac{(M-N\sqrt{A})^{n}}{2\sqrt{A}}$,

$M’==\frac{(M+N\sqrt{A})^{n}}{2}+\frac{(M-N\sqrt{A})^{n}}{2}$

where  $ M$ and $N$ are the basic solutions of $A$

(For example if we choose $A=8$, $N=1$ and $M=3$).

$\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}=M’$,

$\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}-\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}=N’\sqrt{A}$;

$a=2^{-2(n+1)}\Big((M+N\sqrt{A})^{n}+(M-N\sqrt{A})^{n}\Big)^{2}$,

$b=2^{-2(n+1)}\Big((M+N\sqrt{A})^{n}-(M-N\sqrt{A})^{n}\Big)^{2}$.

Let's take an example: $A=13$, $N=180$ and $M=649$,

we choose $n=4$, then

$\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}=1419278889601$,

$a=\frac{1053711982714216551873491874429255128997076465231993345538436469128908160121757992166220331730227201}{256}$,

$b=4116062432477408405755827634489277847644829942312474006009517457534797500475617156899298170821200$.

If we choose $A=8$,$M=3$ and $N=1$ and $n=5$, we get:

$\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}=3363$,

$a=\frac{47370562574818466708936539960450008969}{1024}$,

$b=\frac{5921320321852308338617067495056251121}{128}$,

and so on…

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it's possible if $a$ and $b$ are integers (but not squares).